# jQuery - .children() on a table is not a function

Tags: jquery

So this is the HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Doober durr</th>
        <th>Skippi doober</th>
        <th>Doober duck</th>
        <th>Doober McD</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="v6" placeholder="Mæling 1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="v9" placeholder="Mæling 1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="v12" placeholder="Mæling 1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="v15" placeholder="Mæling 1" />
    </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<button style="float:right;" class="btn btn-primary" id="calc"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span> REIKNA</button>
```

Basically what happens is, the statement

```
$("#calc").click(function () {
        console.log($(this).siblings()[0]);
    });
```

returns the table, but as soon as I try to call `.children()` on the table, it says it's not a function.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `$(this).siblings()[0]` return dom object of table and not jquery object.You can rather pass table selector to siblings method as argument to get the jquery object of table:

```
$("#calc").click(function () {
    console.log($(this).siblings('table').children());
});
```

Comment: @Firkamon: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `$(this).siblings()[0]` returns a dom element reference so it don't have access to jQuery methods.

So if you want to access the element by index then use .eq(index) which will return a jQuery object reference to the element at the said index.

```
$(this).siblings().eq(0).children();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$($(this).siblings()[0]).children()` because the way you've written, you get the DOM object of the table, not the jQuery object.

Comment: This is an elegant solutions as well, wrapping the DOM element again in a jQuery wrapper. `$(this).siblings().eq(0).children()` as suggested by @Razvan Dumitru is even better.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `.prev()`

```
$(this).prev().children()
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).siblings()[0]` is a DOM element. You can get what you want with `$(this).siblings().eq(0).children()` or get the jQ object using the DOM element, but it's kinda ugly.

```
var domEl = $(this).siblings()[0];
var $jQEl = $(domEl);
var $children = $jQEl.children();
```

Good practice: prefix your jQ objects with $.